# Basic programming - array of objects to a multi-dimensional object

Tags: javascript, json, maps, javascript-objects

I've been stuck on this for hours.

I have a list of objects:

```
const myCompanyList = [
    {name: 'coca-cola', size: 'big', color: 'red'},
    {name: 'my-cola', size: 'small', color: 'purple'},
    {name: 'pepsi', size: 'big', color: 'blue'}
];
```

I need to get it into this format:

```
myJson = {
    companies: {
        big: {
            coca-cola: {color: 'red'},
            pepsi: {color: 'blue'}
        },
        small: {
            my-cola: {color: 'purple'}
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried doing this:

```
wrapperObject = {};
innerObject = {};

for each object in myCompanyList {
    innerObject[object.size] = { object.name : {color: object.color}}

}
```

but the object[name] bit overwrites. How can I write this so I can dynamically get names on each object/map level?  Do I need to make another inner object/map to dynamically write the names?

I've tried writing this in Java but I ended up with 5 dimensional maps and it didn't work, so I just wondered if there was something simple I'm missing - answers in Java, javascript or pseudocode thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a map, Try the following :

```js
let myCompanyList = [{name: "coca-cola", size: "big", color: "red"}, {name: "my-cola", size: "small", color: "purple"},{name: "pepsi", size: "big", color:"blue"}];
                 
let result = {};
 
result.companies = myCompanyList.reduce((a,curr)=>{
  a[curr.size] = a[curr.size] || {};
  a[curr.size][curr.name] = {"color" : curr.color};
  return a;
},{});
 console.log(result);
```